# System of differential equation, Euler's method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, eulers-method

Does anyone know if there is any calculator or how can I input this system of differential equation in wolfram?

$$\frac{dy_1}{dt}=0.279\left[-0.125y_1+2y_2-1.25y_C+1.25e\right]$$

$$\frac{dy_2}{dt}=-0.167\left[-0.333y_1+12.5y_2-0.333y_C+0.333e\right]$$

$$\frac{dy_C}{dt}=2y_1$$

And $e$ is a function, defined as

$$e(t) = 210\sin(10\pi t), t \in [0, 30].$$

I've solved this using Euler method, but I want to verify my results and I'm looking for suitable tool.

Diagrams with results:

step = 0.1
[image: step - 0.1]

step = 0.01
[image: step - 0.01]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, what IC stands for?

Comment: Yeah, sure, I forgot to add them, y1 = y2 = yc = 0

Comment: It's for academic purposes :) I've attached a diagram, i1 = y1 and i2=y2.

Comment: I've tried with 0.1

Comment: Sure, attached :)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You can solve this via matrix decomposition so that with the new variable $u=Vy$ the system is decoupled.

Comment: The driving term has 5 oscillations per time unit. You need at least 6, better 10 sampling points per oscillation to start to faithfully capture its shape. This gives an upper bound for a useful step size of $h=1/50=0.02$. This also satisfies $Lh<1$ for the Lipschitz constant at around $L=2$. The first try with $h=0.1$ falls short of the sampling criterion.